# Custom Validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My user control is like:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="_txtLeadDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="_txtLeadDate" ErrorMessage="You cannot select a day earlier than today!" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True">&nbsp;
    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

and the server side code is:

```
protected void CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args){
   if (some condition){
            args.IsValid = false;
   }else{
            args.IsValid = true;
   }
 }
```

But the page is showing error:

> 'ASP.usercontrol_preordercontrol_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'CustomValidator2_ServerValidate' and no extension method 'CustomValidator2_ServerValidate' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.usercontrol_preordercontrol_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: These controls are part of `UserControl`?

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes. these are in user control.

Comment: But, you have written my `asp` page? That's confusing it should be UserControl page right? Alos, you have added this custom validator code in code behind of User Control right?

Comment: Yes. everything is in user control. My bad about mentioning the asp page. will edit it

Comment: Please re-check the names `CustomValidator2_ServerValidate` in both `ascx` & `ascx.cs` file (I knw here you have posted them correctly, but may be you might have misspelled in your actual code) Cz your code looks fine to me.

Comment: yes rahul. its same on ascx and ascx.cs

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin , I would suggest delete events from ascx and code behind and regenerate them once again via ascx, see if that helps!

Comment: @ArindamNayak did that. same error.

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin , if you remove customvalidator and events from ascx and codebehind respectively, does that still errors?

Comment: @ArindamNayak yes. when i remove this complete code, then its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the following event

```
protected void CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
```

is declared in the code behind of your UserControl(*.ascx*) and not the **.aspx** form, from where you're calling this UserControl.

Comment: Again a negative review without a reason. Though its an old post I can still remember it's a valid point. The code behind for your usercontrol event should be declared in the code behind of the user control and NOT on the code behind of the aspx page.